# Prove this inequality $\sum_{cyc}(\frac{1}{a+b})+\frac{3}{a+b+c}\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{ab+bc+ac}}$

Tags: inequality

Let a,b,c are non-negative numbers. Prove the inequality
$$\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{a+c}+\frac{3}{a+b+c}\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{ab+bc+ac}}$$

---

**My idea**: This inequality is homogeneous, we can assume $a+b+c=1$

We have inequality : $$\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{c+a} \geq \frac{a+b+c}{2(ab+bc+ca)} + \frac{3}{a+b+c}(1)$$

We need to prove $\frac{1}{2(ab+bc+ca)}+3\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{ab+bc+ac}}$

But the equality not occurs when $a=b=c$ so it's hard with me.

*Prove* $(1)$: $$LHS=\frac{a+b+c}{a+b}+\frac{a+b+c}{b+c}+\frac{a+b+c}{a+c}$$

$$=\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}+3$$

$RHS=\frac{\left(a+b+c\right)^2}{2\left(ab+bc+ac\right)}+3$

$$\Rightarrow LHS=\frac{a^2}{ab+ac}+\frac{b^2}{ab+bc}+\frac{c^2}{ac+bc}\ge \frac{\left(a+b+c\right)^2}{2\left(ab+bc+ac\right)}=RHS$$

Comment: Let $x:= (ab +bc +ca)$, then your last inequality reads: $\frac{1}{2x}+3\ge\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, that can be transformed by equivalence transformations into $1+8x+36x^2\ge0$, which always holds for $x\ge0$.

Comment: LoL tks everyone very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}=t$.

You need to prove $$\frac{1}{2t^2}+3 \ge \frac{1}{t}$$
Or
$$ 6t^2-2t+1 \ge 0$$
Which is obviously true since discriminant of above quadratic is negative.

Comment: i think it's $6t^2-2t+1\ge0 $

Comment: @Word Oh Yeah! My bad 